# Regular Expressions using Substitution to convert numbers

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I'm a Python beginner, so keep in mind my regex skills are level -122.

I need to convert a string with text containing `file1` to `file01`, but not convert `file10` to `file010`.

My program is wrong, but this is the closest I can get, I've tried dozens of combinations but I can't get close:

```
import re
txt = 'file8, file9, file10'
pat = r"[0-9]"
regexp = re.compile(pat)
print(regexp.sub(r"0\d", txt))
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my pattern and substitution and give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the number and check the length before adding 0, but you might be able to use this instead:

```
import re
txt = 'file8, file9, file10'
pat = r"(?<!\d)(\d)(?=,|$)"
regexp = re.compile(pat)
print(regexp.sub(r"0\1", txt))
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/bA3xC6)

`(?<! ... )` is called a negative lookbehind. This prevents (negative) a match if the pattern after it has the pattern in the negative lookbehind matches. For example, `(?<!a)b` will match all `b` in a string, except if it has an `a` before it, meaning `bb`, `cb` matches, but `ab` doesn't match. `(?<!\d)(\d)` thus matches a digit, unless it has another digit before it.

`(\d)` is a single digit, enclosed in a capture group, denoted by simple parentheses. The captured group gets stored in the first capture group.

`(?= ... )` is a positive lookahead. This matches *only* if the pattern inside the positive  lookahead matches after the pattern before this positive lookahead. In other words, `a(?=b)` will match all `a` in a string only if there's a `b` after it. `ab` matches, but `ac` or `aa` don't.

`(?=,|$)` is a positive lookahead containing `,|$` meaning either a comma, or the end of the string.

`(?<!\d)(\d)(?=,|$)` thus matches any digit, as long as there's no digit before it and there's a comma after it, or if that digit is at the end of the string.

Comment: dammit, i wrote the exact same code, but you beat me to this :P

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Oops, sorry ^^;

Comment: Okay, I have to ask, can you explain the logic behind all the symbols in the pat? I know \d is digit and | alternative, but the rest - especially in that order confuses me? I don't think I would have ever come on that on my own

Comment: @user2780635 Okay, I'll add an explanation in a moment.

Comment: @user2780635 Heh, there's no reason not to :)

Comment: @user2780635 Updated my answer with explanations.

Comment: that explains so much and that website you gave me is coming in handy, thanks again Jerry!

Comment: @user2780635 All the pleasure is mine :)

Answer (score 0):

how about?

```
a='file1'    
a='file' + "%02d" % int(a.split('file')[1])
```

Comment: sorry, gotta use substitution regex for this assignment, but that is a much easier answer!

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses a regex to find every sequence of digits and `str.zfill` to pad with zeros:

```
>>> txt = 'file8, file9, file10'
>>> re.sub(r'\d+', lambda m : m.group().zfill(2), txt)
'file08, file09, file10'
```